# How can I setup a source to host data for an iOS app

Tags: ios, json

I have some experience using JSON to pull data from a .asp page.
How would I go about creating my own JSON formatted data source and placing that on a server?

Any other ideas to accomplish this task?

I basically have a spreadsheet of information that I would like to store somewhere and pull that data into an iOS app.

Comment: What language are you wanting to create the json source in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use any language. For my apps we use a PHP Webservice. There are numerous tutorials out there about how to create a JSON WebService that you host on your webserver and your mobile app communicates with.

[Here](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) is a VERY basic xml / json service that uses php and mysql.  This should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up with a hosting company that supports PHP.  Read instructions on where to place your PHP page. Create a PHP page and use its JSON library call.

Do something like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $arr = array ('name'=>'Bill','age'=>18,'gender'=>'m');
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

http://is.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [Parse](https://parse.com/products/core) can be very helpful when the support of a server-side implementation is required. Also, Parse supports RESTful apis and JSON.

Checkout their iOS [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS); It's very thorough.